# SQL query for calculating number of days and nights

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am looking for a query that tells number of days and nights while travelling
my day time ends at 18:00 and after that night time starts
night time ends at 09:00 
query that tells how many days and night a person has traveled

Comment: so your day is from 9:00 to 18:00 and night is from 18:00 to 9:00?

Comment: yes day is from 9:00 to 18:00 and night is from 18:00 to 9:00

Comment: @Rohit Manpower, Make it easy to help you and for a stranger to find an answer to a similar problem. It would be helpful if you could present a sample of your data and the code or ideas that you have.